# Redirecting a WWW.domain.org to domain.org

Tags: iis-7.5

I tried to setup the rewrite rules, but it doesn't appear to be working right. My www.domain.org still ends up at www. What am I missing here?

My redirect to HTTPS from the domain.org works correctly.

```
<rewrite>  <rules>
<rule name="Redirect www.xxx.com to xxx.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^www\.tdccf\.org$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://tdccf.org/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>  </rules> </rewrite>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have the `{HTTPS}` input specified, not `{HTTP_HOST}`.  The `{HTTPS}` input contains the literal value `on` or `off` which would never match the regex `^www\.tdccf\.org$`.  `{HTTP_HOST}`, on the other hand, contains the host portion of the request.

```
<rewrite>  <rules>
<rule name="Redirect www.xxx.com to xxx.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.tdccf\.org$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://tdccf.org/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>  </rules> </rewrite>
```

See the [MSDN documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) for full information on the match syntax.